# React app on server while refreshing the page shows 404 page

Tags: reactjs

I am build the react app using the `create_react_app`. Now i move the build to the server and run the app using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). My app will load the data from the apis. When i refresh the page it shows 404 page not found error. Also i tried with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

When i was some page `/dashboard` and refersh the page it shows 404. Now i have to go to `BASE_URL/` then only it works. But in my local when i refersh everything works.

This is my package.json

```
"react-dates": "^17.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.0",
"react-i18next": "^7.7.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4"
```

And i use `apache` on my server.

I think this is the problem not with my code. If you guys know anything about this, please help me.

And `http-server` run command was `http-server ./build -p 7001`

Comment: what kind of server environment are you using

Comment: aws, ubuntu server. But i don't know what you mean by server environment

Comment: I mean Apache, Nginx etc

Comment: i use apache in my server

Comment: if you have .htaccess file in your root directory then in order to make it work you have to Enable **mod_rewrite** on your server follow step 1 and step 2 of this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 34):

In order to avoid 404 error on Apache server you would have to enable **mod_rewrite** and add **.htaccess** file in root directory

**Step 1 — Enabling mod_rewrite**

First, we need to activate **mod_rewrite**. It's available but not enabled with a clean Apache 2 installation.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already enabled. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Step 2 — Setting Up .htaccess**

By default, Apache prohibits using an **.htaccess** file to apply rewrite rules, so first you need to allow changes to the file. Open the default Apache configuration file using nano or your favorite text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Inside that file, you will find a **< VirtualHost *:80>** block starting on the first line. Inside of that block, add the following new block so your configuration file looks like the following. Make sure that all blocks are properly indented.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

And if you have https configured, you will find a **< VirtualHost *:443>** block starting on the first line. Inside of that block, add the following new block so your configuration file looks like the following. Make sure that all blocks are properly indented. In this case, you also need to add this below 2 virtual hosts of HTTP and HTTPS

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close the file. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Step 3 — creating .htaccess**

Now, create the following .htaccess file in the web root.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

> If you have already enabled mod_rewrite and applied rewrite rules the skip step 1 and step 2 and use step 3 directly
>
> I have referred documentation of [React](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) and server setup by [digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 6):

If you’re using Apache HTTP Server, you need to create a .htaccess file in the public folder that looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

according to create-react-app documentation
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: i created the .htaccess file inside the public folder but still i am getting the same 404 page only

Comment: have redirects from http to https?

Comment: but service workers need https encryption... that can affect this

Comment: I solved that using `HashRouter`. Before i used `BrowserRouter`. Now my only problem removing the # from url. That i will lookout later. But i don't know what i did was right or wrong

Answer (score 6):

To expound more on [sparsh turkane' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396231/10907864), I had this challenge when working on a CentOS server.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The `mod_rewrite` module is enabled by default on CentOS. If you find it is not enabled on your server, you can enable it by editing `00-base.conf` file located in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/` directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
```

Add or uncomment the following line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Save and close the file.

Now we can set up the URL rewrites by creating an `.htaccess` file in your default document root directory. A `.htaccess` file allows us to modify rewrite rules without accessing server configuration files. For this reason, `.htaccess` is critical to your web server:

Change directories to your Document root. For me it was `/var/www/my_app`:

```
cd /var/www/my_app
```

Create the `.htaccess` file:

```
sudo nano .htaccess
```

Add the following content:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Save and exit the file.

Next, we need to allow Apache to read `.htaccess` files located under the Document root directory. For me it was `/var/www/my_app`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/my_app">
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Save and close the file, then restart the httpd service:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

**Resources**: [Install And Configure Mod_rewrite For Apache On CentOS 7](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/#:%7E:text=restart%20firewalld.service-,Enable%20mod_rewrite%20Module,.modules.d%2F%20directory.)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not using default apache vHost config like **:80* and instead using domains like **test.local** for local test environments please refer this, this worked for me.

I had to add `<Directory>` tag and do the Rewrite codes

```
<VirtualHost react.myapp.local>

    ServerName react.myapp.local
    ServerAdmin react.myapp.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/react-myapp/build"

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/react-myapp/build">
        RewriteEngine On
        #check for files and do not redirect
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        #rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/react.myapp.local-error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I was using XAMPP in Windows and I wanted to host a react app in my local apache server.