# Error on refreshing subdirectory in apache2

Tags: apache2

I'm running a webapp on apache2 on digital ocean. for example, if my domain is example.com I can goto example.com and example.com/foo/bar but when I'm on example.com/foo/bar page and refresh it shows a 404 error.

Here's my 000.default.conf:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Thanks and please let me know if you need more detail

Answer (score 0):

I followed this resource to solve it: [React app on server while refreshing the page shows 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357947/react-app-on-server-while-refreshing-the-page-shows-404-page)

just needed to add some configs to sites-available and a .htaccess